# Issue connecting new repo with local folder

Tags: github, command-line

I am doing a poor job on learning how to properly set-up a local folder with github.

Here are the steps I have done.

1: cd to the folder I want to connect to.
2: git init
3: git remote add origin master (repo link .git)
4: git push origin master

at step 4 I get the following issue:
Georges-MacBook-Pro-2:meetlete georgeconnolly$ git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/grobconnolly/meetlete.git'

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did see your repository, it contains `README.md`. While your local repository does not contain anything.

Which creates conflict with your global repo (A common mistake).

You can perform below steps.

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/grobconnolly/meetlete.git
$ git checkout -b main
$ git pull origin main --no-rebase
$ git push origin main
```

Here `pull --no-rebase` will append remote objects to local. And `checkout -b` will create a new branch named **main** (Else git default will generate branch `master`).

Comment: Thank you for the response. In the future, how can I avoid this?  git pull somewhere in the process.

Comment: You may avoid this by unchecking the checkbox of `Add a README file` while creating a new repository on GitHub.